# VSCode: files not in project open in a separate window

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I double click a file to open it from the finder, it opens in the currently open/focused project/window. IMO, this is a bad default.

I need files to open in the current window ONLY if they are in the project of that window.

Can this be set? Where do I set it?

Comment: It opens in the current window, like I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it. You can add this line to your project's or global settings file.

```
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
```

### Note

If you are using the cli tool there is also an easy way to do it:

```
code yourfile --new-window
```